# How to add onchange to a custom option (drop-down)

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, dropdown-attribute

This should be simple but for some reason I can't find a solution.

I have some custom options that are listed on a drop down

[image]
[image]

I'd like to call a javascript function when the user changes the option.
This is the select tag that I'm looking for

[image]

I looked into ...catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtm,...catalog/product/view/options/view/options.phtm, and into some additional files but it's nowhere to be found. Any idea about where should I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php
```